# Filter function returning empty array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a component that receives a parameter.

I use that parameter to compare and filter out only those elements that are equal to the value of the parameter.
but when I use the `filter` function it gives an empty array.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**
In the filter function if i use `parseInt(this.props.match.params)` it works..
but doesn't work if i use `parseInt(this.state.registrationId)` any ideas..

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Progress from "../Common/Progress";
class AdmissionProcess extends Component {
    state = {
        progress: true,
        enquiries: [],
        registrationId: this.props.match.params.reg_status
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.loadData()
    }
    componentDidUpdate  = (prevProps) => {
        if(prevProps.match.params.reg_status !== this.props.match.params.reg_status) {
            this.setState({registrationId: this.props.match.params.reg_status})
            console.log("I ran")
        }
    }
    loadData () {
        const url = window.domain+"/list-enquiry";
        fetch(url)
        .then(res =>  res.json())
        .then(result => this.setState({enquiries: [...result], progress: false}))
        .catch(err =>  console.log("err"+ " " +err))
    }

    checkEnquiries = () => {
        const reg2 = this.state.enquiries.filter(enq => enq.registrationId===this.state.registrationId)
        console.log(reg2)
    }

    render() {
        this.checkEnquiries()
        return(
          {/* Jsx code here*/}
        )
    }
 export default AdmissionProcess
```

Comment: Could you please log your `result` in the fetch??

Comment: Hi @RyanLe,  I logged result in fetch it shows array of objects... as expected

Comment: are they both numbers or string? you use === equality

Comment: *"an undefined array*": what would that be? Either it is `undefined` or an array, but not both. And `filter` *never* returns `undefined`, so what do you mean?

Comment: @HDM91 one of them is string , but i also tried parseInt() function in the one that's string but still same result

Comment: @trincot it returns an empty array..

Comment: please attach the result of array and state.registrationId

Comment: Fixed it in your question.

Comment: @HDM91, i have attached the image for the array and this.state.registrationId is 2

Comment: @KaushikGarkoti have you checked my answer? If is not working or is not what you are looking for let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: load data may called before checkEnquiries , because you call checkEnquiries in the render function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after several hit and trials i managed to get it work ... I'll be honest i still don't know exactly how it works and i would really appreciate some explanation on how this works and others don't... Here's the code with changes...

```html
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Progress from "../Common/Progress";
class AdmissionProcess extends Component {
    state = {
        progress: true,
        enquiries: [],
        registrationId: this.props.match.params.reg_status,
        requiredList: []
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.loadData()
    }

    loadData () {
        const url = window.domain+"/list-enquiry";
        fetch(url)
        .then(res =>  res.json())
        .then(result => this.setState({enquiries: [...result], progress: false}, this.checkEnquiries))
        .catch(err =>  console.log("err"+ " " +err))
    }

    componentDidUpdate  = (prevProps) => {
        if(prevProps.match.params.reg_status !== this.props.match.params.reg_status) {
            this.setState({registrationId: this.props.match.params.reg_status}, this.checkEnquiries)
            console.log("I ran")
        }
    }

    checkEnquiries = () => {
        const reg2 = this.state.enquiries.filter((enq) => enq.registrationId === parseInt(this.state.registrationId))
        this.setState({requiredList: [...reg2]})
    }

    render() {
        return ({/*JSX Code Here*/})
    }
}
export default AdmissionProcess
```

Comment: Exactly what I suggested to you: call `this.checkEnquiries` on `setState`'s callback... And the explanation still the same: you are filtering an empty array because data needs to come from fetch.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I agree and thanks for pointing that out earlier.. but i followed your approach earlier but it didn't work.. maybe because i was calling it like this -- ``  loadData () {
        const url = window.domain+"/list-enquiry";
        fetch(url)
        .then(res =>  res.json())
        .then(result => this.setState({enquiries: [...result], progress: false}, () => this.checkEnquiries()))
        .catch(err =>  console.log("err"+ " " +err))
    }``

Comment: edited code block  --  `` loadData () { ``
const url = window.domain+"/list-enquiry"; 
fetch(url) .then(res => res.json()) .then(result => this.setState({enquiries: [...result], progress: false}, () => this.checkEnquiries())) .catch(err => console.log("err"+ " " +err)) }``

Comment: `setState({...}, () => this.checkEnquiries())` or `setState({...}, () => {this.checkEnquiries()})` it's the same thing

Comment: but in my answer i am doing 
`setState({...}, this.checkEnquiries)`

Answer (score 0):

note that your `loadData()` crush the initial `state`, try this code :

```
loadData () {
    const url = window.domain+"/list-enquiry";
    fetch(url)
    .then(res =>  res.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({...this.state, enquiries: [...result], progress: false}))
    .catch(err =>  console.log("err"+ " " +err))
}


checkEnquiries = () => {
    const reg2 = this.state.enquiries.filter(enq => enq.registrationId===parseInt(this.state.registrationId))
    console.log(reg2)
}
```

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito `this.setState({enquiries: [...result], progress: false}))` => `state` in this case will have 2 proprty : `enquiries` and `progress`,

`this.setState({...this.state, enquiries: [...result], progress: false}))` => `state` in this case will have 3 proprty : `enquiries`, `registrationId`  and `progress`,

Comment: @KaushikGarkoti, can you show us how you call your `AdmissionProcess ` component, what is the value of `this.props.match.params.reg_status`

Comment: this.props.match.params.reg_status value depends on from which page it came.. right now it's 5.

Comment: I edited my post, can you tell me if it's work or not

Comment: Note that in your `state` declaration, `registrationId` equal to `this.props.match.params.reg_status`, but in your question's body, you mention `parseInt(this.props.match.params)`

Comment: still returns empty array